# What are the downsides to saying a file is NULL instead of closing it?

Tags: c

If I've defined and opened a file I've decided to call `f`, what are the consequences of simply saying `f = NULL` as opposed to properly closing the file, with `fclose()`?

Or does `f = NULL` not even work?

Comment: Leaking resources.

Comment: `f = NULL` does not close the file handle, it throws it away

Comment: c has no garbage collector.

Comment: To clarify "leaking resources" part - file descriptors are a finite resource, if your program has a long enough lifetime on the system, it might eventually deprive entire system of file descriptors, because there can be only so many files opened at once, meaning that it will block any other program from doing IO operations as it can't open any other file as ones that were opened were never closed, until the program exits, or in worst case, until the OS reboots (realtime OS or some OS from 90's will probably not release them after the program exits, bleh).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as opposed to languages with a garbage collector (like `python`), setting the file pointer to `NULL` just loses the reference on the file handle, but it does *not* close the file.

Which leads to potential bugs, like buffers not flushed, locked files, reaching the "too many open files per process" limit... depending on the open mode and the platform you're on.

On "modern" systems supporting ressource tracking, the file is still closed on exit (still you may lose some buffers), but some legacy systems will retain the file open until you reboot (and if your code is a plugin of some bigger tool, resource tracking doesn't apply until the bigger tool is closed)

Which is considered as good practice is to set the handle to `NULL` *after* having closed the file so no risk of calling `fclose` again on a closed file (it *reduces* the risk but there could be copies of the handle, so it's not 100% safe):

```
if (f!=NULL)
{
  fclose(f);
  f = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `f` to NULL, all it does is overwrite the value of the variable `f`, losing the reference to the `FILE` object it pointed to.

The resources used by the `FILE` object don't get cleaned up as `fclose` is never called.